# Rails 3 Routes - prepend all url paths with set string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've been asked to change the routes on a Rails project such that the routes will only respond to requests where the app name (or other arbitrary string) is the first string after the domain name, e.g.

`www.thething.com/appname/users/sign_in` instead of `www.thething.com/users/sign_in`

`www.thething.com/appname` instead of `www.thething.com`

`www.thething.com/appname/search` instead of `www.thething.com/search`

I've suggested using a subdomain `appname.thething.com` instead, but the client is quite specific about wanting the URL in the above format.

`www.thething.com` will be a splash page which will contain a link to `www.thething.com/appname`, with the intention of adding additional apps/pages in future with new folder names.

Is there an easy way of modifying the routes file so that all routes will get the `.../appname` prepended to all resources and routes, while being after the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is wrap all existing routes in: `namespace :appname do` ... `end`, like so:

```
# config/routes.rb
Appname::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :appname do
    # existing routes go here
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but it will prepend `/appname` to all the routes.

Comment: is there any way to do this without altering the path helpers?